# EpiServer Community issue. Access denied when login with administrator

Tags: episerver

We have recently deployed a web site which is based on EpiServer CMS 6 and Relate Plus 2.

Everything works but there is a strange issue with the CMS:

When we login with "administrator" account which is a member of Administrators, CommunityAdmins, CommunityModerators, WebAdmins and WebEditors groups, we can go to CMS and access all the tabs (e.g. Admin, Edit,Visitor Groups, Reports). However, same account does see the "Community" menu, but not the "Moderation Mode" and "Admin Mode" sub-menus.

If we try to access the community administrator (or moderation) pages directly through their url, we get "Access Denied".

Has anybody experienced something similar before?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the default role and membership providers?

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight mistake in the access rights section.
You need to see if this is what is present in web.config file:

```
<allow roles="CommunityAdmins,Administrators,..." />
    <deny users="*" />
```

And not:

```
<deny users="*" />
<allow roles="CommunityAdmins,Administrators,..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.config: Check the AdministratorsGroupName setting and the authorization settings in the location element of "EPiServerCommunity".

Also check that episerver.shell/protectedeModules contains something like this:

```
<add name="Community" resourcePath="~/EPiServerCommunity">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="EPiServer.Community.Web.Administration"/>
    <add assembly="EPiServer.Community.Gadgets"/>
  </assemblies>
</add>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help John, AdministratorsGroupName  is set to Administrators. The other settings you mentioned are in web.config too. This site used to work with same web.config file. This issue happened when we made some changes on the code and released the application again (same DB, modified code and web.config)

Comment: thanks for the reply. The config is just like what you mentioned but the problem is not fixed yet. any suggestions?